# Projection over the first and last element in a ternary relation in Alloy

Tags: alloy

How Can I project over the first and the last column in a ternary relation in Alloy?

Suppose I have `r1: A->B->C` and assume `r1= (A0->B1->C1,A1->B1->C0, A2->B0->C2)`, How can I define `r2: A->C` to be `r2= (A0->C1,A1->C0, A2->C2)`

More concretely if I have:

> sig A{r1:B->C, r2:C}
>
> sig B{}
>
> sig C{}

How can I constrain r2 to become projection of r1 over the first and last column.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [a recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921494/alloy-using-set-comprehension-on-binary-relationships).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to put the constraint into the signature:

```
sig A{r1:B->C, r2:C}{
  r2 = r1[B]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define r1 in terms of r2

```
open util/ternary

sig A{
    r2:C,
    r1:B->r2
}

sig B{}
sig C{}

check { select13[r1] in r2 } for 3
```

If you need a way to generally get the first and last of a triple, use the select13 from the util/ternary

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following fact seems to also serve as a solution to this problem:

> fact {all a:A,c:C | (a->c) in r2 iff some b:B | (a->b->c) in r1 }